# How to install enchant C library for pyenchant on python anywhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, pythonanywhere, pyenchant, enchant

On python anywhere, you aren't allowed to use sudo. So I can't run sudo apt-get install python-enchant

I tried to use linuxbrew to install enchant however, I can't install linuxbrew because the script requires sudo.

This script gives me an error saying that I need to be sudo:

```
apt-get install python-enchant
```

What kind of works:
I was able to use

```
apt-get download python-enchant
dpkg -x python-enchant ./
```

This also works:

```
apt-get source python-enchant
```

These are steps I found from other tutorials for installing things without sudo. However, when I import enchant, the library still can't be found. Do I need to move the extracted file somewhere?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Users are not able to install system packages on PythonAnywhere. You may install pypi package but the `libenchant` has to be pre-installed by admins.